# StyleCop Plus: Cant find configuration dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2013, stylecop, stylecop-plus

I installed Style Cop Plus from Nuget. I know it is installed and doing its thing because I see 
wantings like this one:

```
SP2001 Warning  5   SP2001 : StyleCopPlus.StyleCopPlus : Only tab characters are allowed to be used for indentation.    D:\Users\Chad\Desktop\TypeScript\One\WebApplication4\Classes\Class1.cs  4   1   WebApplication4
```

However, this is in conflict with other static code analysis, not sure from where.

```
Warning 5   SA1027 : CSharp.Spacing : Tabs are not allowed. Use spaces instead. D:\Users\Chad\Desktop\TypeScript\One\WebApplication4\Classes\Class1.cs  4   1   WebApplication4
```

Prior to installing Style Code Plus, I already had Style Cop installed.

Clearly I have to turn off one of these warnings since they are in conflict with one another. I am trying to figure out where the rules can be configured for each.

If I ..

```
1. go to Project -> Properties -> Code Analysis Tab
2. Click the Open Rules button next to "MS recommended Rules" 
3. Search for "SP2001" and "SA1027"
```

..neither is found

However, I do find SA1027 in the Style Cop rules by doing the following

```
1. Project Explorer select Project, right mouse => Style Cop Settings 
. Find SA1027
```

SP2001, as the message indicates, is clearly a Style Cop Plus rule.

Referring to the [Codeplex StyleCop Plus web page](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/), I see in the documentation a Style Copy Plus dialog that looks like the following but I am unable to find it.

Where do I find the configurations screen for StyleCop Plus to turn off SA1027?

[image]

**Update**

From the above referenced web page:

*As soon as StyleCop+ is installed correctly, you should see new "StyleCop+" tab appeared in settings dialog.
This tab contains settings page for configuring all StyleCop+ features.*

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot imagine how StyleCop+ could be installed via NuGet. Even if it's possible I have nothing to do with it and cannot help therefore. I would recommend you going to StyleCop+ page on CodePlex, downloading the original DLL and putting it into StyleCop folder. Let me know if it helps, thanks!

Comment: Also, when you go to "StyleCop Settings" dialog - do you see a "StyleCop+" as a last tab there?

Comment: When I tried to place the StyleCopLus.dll in the StyleCop folder and then run VS2013, I get this: ---------------------------
StyleCop
---------------------------
An exception occurred while loading one of the StyleCop add-ins: System.IO.FileLoadException, Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\StyleCop 4.7\StyleCopPlus.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: NO, the tab is missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as Oleg suggested, I copied the StyleCopPlus.dll to the StyleCop folder. But then I decided to click the Properties of the file and click the "Unblock" button. This was the missing step. Thanks, Oleg!

Comment: Oh yeah, it's documented here https://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quick%20Start%20Guide, but I know nobody reads that :) Anyway glad it worked finally!